# Importing data into SCIP solver

Tags: excel, scip

Is it possible to import data into SCIP from Excel (and then export results to Excel)? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [SCIP](https://www.scipopt.org/) has presented some useful solutions to deal with it.

- First, by using an interactive shell, which I don't know has the capability to connect with the separate sheet software like excel.
- The second, by using a low-level API like C/C++, [python](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt), etc. I think you could write your own model in your favorite language through the many capabilities of IDEs/code writers such as sheet read methods.
- The third, by connecting SCIP with some of the algebraic modeling languages like [GAMS](http://www.gams.com) or [AMPL](https://ampl.com/). I knew that GAMS has the last version of SCIP by default and you can easily read your separate sheet data in GAMS and solving the problem by SCIP solver.

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Yes very helpful, thanks a lot Mr. Omidi.
Otherwise, for GAMS and AMPL, are there limits on the model size for also the open source solvers or only for the commercial ones. Also, which one would you advise me to use? I believe that AMPL is easier to learn.

Comment: @O. Sd, as far as I know, GAMS and AMPL are commercial softwares and whose free version is limited. At least for GAMS as I have experienced with that. The good news is, there is an optimization host that supports many of solvers, commercial and open source. Would you see [neos](https://neos-server.org/neos/index.html)?

Comment: By using the commercial solvers in neos, will I be able to benefit these with their maximum performance without the need for commercial licenses? because I used Gurobi in opensolver with the academic but I was not satisfied with the results obtained in term of resolution time. I don't know if it will be the same in neos. Also, from what I noticed, resolving a problem in the neos server makes it publicly available, is that true? Finaly MrOmidi, is it possible to estimate in advance the resolution time of an optimization problem? Thank you again Mr Omidi for your precious help.

Comment: @O.Sd, as far as I know, the neos provides an academic license for many of the commercial solvers and you are being able to use them by accepting the neos using agreement (for non-commercial usage). If you have any issues, I recommend contacting the neos support team. About `resolving a problem in the neos server makes it publicly available, is that true?`, I really don't know. For the last question, If the problem at hand is MILP, I think it is very complicating to estimate the resolution time.

Comment: alright, thank you again Mr Omidi